# setText from Textview can't be set when returning back from the activity

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, textview, countdowntimer

I am using the countdowntimer to countdown Here is my code:

```
public class countdownnow extends Activity{

    TextView tv;
    private CDwnTimer countDownTimer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        setContentView(R.layout.countdown_disp);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    countDownTimer = new MalibuCountDownTimer(30000, 1050);
        countDownTimer.start();
}


// CountDownTimer class
    public class CDwnTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public CDwnTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("00");             
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            int convert = (int)  millisUntilFinished/1000;
            String testString = String.format("%02d",convert); 

    CharSequence cs = new String(testString);                   
    tv.setText(cs);                 
        }
    }
}
```

Initially this works fine but when I leave this activity and then go to another activity then come back, the textview does not countdown anymore? TextView tv continues to run through the line but it does not update.  Is the activity freed up and initialize the same id of the Textview?  Any hints would be great.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How did you leave the activity?

I simulated your program and when I leave MainActivity to the OtherActivity and go back, the textView keep counting down. The code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private CDwnTimer countDownTimer;
private Button btn;
private TextView tv;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // call sendMessage method
            Intent startActivityIntent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(startActivityIntent);
        }
    });

    countDownTimer = new CDwnTimer(30000, 1050);
    countDownTimer.start();
}



// CountDownTimer class
    public class CDwnTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public CDwnTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("00");             
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int convert = (int)  millisUntilFinished/1000;
            String testString = String.format("%02d",convert); 
            CharSequence cs = new String(testString);  
            tv.setText(cs);
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml file for MainActivity layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:layout_weight="6"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="282dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The code is actually off another activity.  It is not the main activity.  What I did was have a menu as the main activity.  Select this code as another activity (which is a button that starts an intent).  Let the counter decrement on the textview which works the first time.  I then click back to the main menu and selected another activity (not the display of countdown) then clicked back out of that and then went to that same activity and had this problem (not counting down).  Sorry if I did not specify it as the main activity or not.  Hope this clarifies what to look.